# editedObject undeclared

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

In my code I have a pretty simple

```
[editedObject setValue:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] forKey:editedFieldKey];
```

however my compiler is telling me "editedObject undeclared" as well as "editedFieldKey". This looks like I didn't `#import` an API but I don't know what I need to import.

Comment: Can you post a little more code? It seems that as the compiler said you didn't declare editedObject and editedFieldKey in the current scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Doesn't have anything to do with #import unless those properties belong to another class. In which case the properties would still have to be defined.

Check where you've defined

> editedObject
>     editedFieldKey

In your code.

You should have something in .h or .m that declares them as objects (or for editedFieldKey, a constant)

"#define editedFieldKey @"somekey"
NSString *editedObject;

or something close to that, editedObject could be any object.

Comment: ok i see what you are saying. Unfortunately tho i never did find it so i just took it out of my code, but thanks anyway.